# How to give a friendly name to the image that we are uploading for the image using kendo ui upload

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, knockout-mvc

I have a requriement that i need to provide an additional name to the file that i am uploading. 
So, in the template i have given a textbox. I need to pass the text box value to controller and need to save the file friendly name.

But, i need to provide the valdiation for the files that are duplicate or not. If the file is duplicate i am preventing the file from being uploading in onupload function. But the file is removing if the friendly name is duplicate. I want to see the file in the upload control even if we do the `e.preventDefault()` method.

```
   $("#images").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "/Image/UploadCampaignImages",
        removeUrl: "remove",
        autoUpload: false
    },
    template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html()),
    success: onSuccess,
    multiple: false,     
    select: onSelect,        
    upload: function (e) {
       if(duplicate)
       {
          // the below code is removing the file. what i need is it should not hit controller
          // method and it should not remove the file that is uploaded. 
          e.perventDefault();
       }
    }
});
```

File Upload template:

```
<script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <span class='k-progress'></span>
    <div class='file-wrapper'>
       <img id="campaignImage" height="40" width="40" />
       <i class='file-heading file-name-heading'>#=name#</i>
       <input type='text' id="txtFriendlyName" class="form-control" placeholder="Alt text" />
       <button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you not using MVC wrappers? Move Friendly Name textbox out side the File Uploader and pass it as additional param to the controller

Comment: @HaBo For that instance only i am using single upload, I want to upload multiple images and want to assign different names for the images. Then how can i do that.